# Not able to see the filter option with Django class based views

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filters

I have the below two views :

```
class BookApiView(APIView):
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
    search_fields = ('title',)
    authentication_classes = (JSONWebTokenAuthentication, )
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, IsNotBlacklistedUser)

    def get(self, request):
        books = Book.objects.filter(
            user=request.user.id, is_published=True).order_by('-title')
        serializer = BookSerializer(books, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(get, request):
        data = request.data
        serializer = BookSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save(user=request.user)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=201)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=400)

class AllBookViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = AllBookSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
    search_fields = ('title',)

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Book.objects.all()
        title = self.request.query_params.get('title', None)
        if title is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(
                title__contains=title, is_published=True)
        queryset = queryset.filter(is_published=True)
        return queryset
```

They both work on the same model. However with one(AllBookViewSet) i can see the filter option on the django rest framework UI and with the other one i cannot.

Is django filter no applicable for class based views . I am assuming that should not be the case but then where am i going wrong here. Please help

Answer (score 0):

That's because Django itself doesn't provide any filter class/method like Django Rest Framework do.

As you can see, the one that you can use `filter_backends` was inherited from `APIView` which provided by Django Rest Framework and the other was inherited from `viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet` which provided by Django. So you can't apply `filter_backends` for `AllBookViewSet`.

**How to achieve that?**

There are 2 ways that you can use to filter the data on the view:

1. Custom `get_queryset` method on `AllBookViewSet` (**not recommend**).
2. Use [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html) to create filter backend for your class-based views. There also a way for you to integrate this kind of filter into `rest_framework`'s
   views.

So, give it a try.

Comment: I did , has the same results . I cannot see any option to filter in the django rest framework UI